# iOS drag tableview cell object onto map view

Tags: ios, uitableview, drag-and-drop, mkmapview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am looking for a way to drag and drop an element in a tableview and drop it as an annotation on a map view in a split view controller. Does anyone know a general approach I should take to this or have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can we see code of your failed attempts?

Comment: I wouldn't think of it as dragging the cell it's self but think of a good graphic/fake cell or annotation to pop up at that moment to drag to the map but then that brings up another problem of how do you tell between a drag and trying to scroll the table. If your table and map are in a view some how and your table is not the default table and small then I could see that happening perhaps with a long press gesture to signal that the user is ready to drag and from your cell and for a graphic to pop up that's draggable. Some more information though could help a us give you a better answer though.